# Improving speed on a 4 nested for loop in R (Rcpp)?

Tags: r, for-loop

Let's assume I have a data frame with 1000 entries/rows. Each row has an ID, a 2nd column with some data, and a 3rd column also with some data.

So the data frame would look something like:

```
ID    yesNo   Id_specific_data
1     1       4
2     0       8
3     0       43
4     1       11
5     0       9
```

... and so on.

I now need to do the following:

```
n = 4

ID_range <- c(1:n)
ID_spec_data <- floor(runif(n, min=10, max=100))
yesNo_data <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n)

df <- data.frame("ID" = ID_range, "yesNo" = yesNo_data, "ID_specific_data" = ID_spec_data)

m <- 1
for (i in seq(1, 100, 1)) {
    for (j in seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)) {
        log_like_list <- c()
        for (k in seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)) {
            total_ID_list <- c()
            for (l in seq(1, length(df$ID))) {

                x = (df$ID_specific_data[[l]]*k - j) / (i*j)
                calc = pnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
                total_ID_list[[l]] = calc
            }

            # log likelihood function
            final_calc = sum(df$yesNo*log(total_ID_list)+(1-df$yesNo)*log(1 - total_ID_list))
            log_like_list[[m]] = final_calc

            m <- m + 1
        }

    }
}
```

So basically the end result (`log_like_list`) should be a list/vector with `1500*200*100` values. But in order to do this the same amount of calculations is needed to be done on the number of ID's in the data frame (which is about 500-1000 in my case). All in all - a lot of calculations.

I know for loops are probably the worst thing you can do in terms of speed, but I'm not even sure that using `apply` would make it super fast when it's this many calculations ? I have read about `Rcpp`, which in principle could reduce calculation time the most of any option. But it requires knowledge of C++ as I can see (which I really lack), and I'm not even sure if it is applicable to my problem here ?

So could the calculation times be reduced significantly with any R tricks, or do I just have to wait it out ?

Comment: First, this isn't reproducible as it is missing `{}` for loop termination. Secondly, the major issue you are running into is [growing objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#Page=13) with respect to the result holders. In advance, you know the length of the output object by are initializing with `c()` instead of `vector('list', 3)`

Comment: Please read [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.

Comment: To update this a bit further, could you provide us with the expected output? Doing a few quick calculations would indicate the `i`,`j`, and `k` loops run together for 29,820,000 different items for `log_like_list`. Is that your intent? (Lengths based off the `length(seq(from, to))` given in post.)

Comment: I think you've got things inside loops that are going to cause you problems.  `       log_like_list <- c()
        m <- 1`  should be outside and not resetting each time, also why are you using `c()` and  not `list()` if you want a list?

Comment: Please provide some expected output. You're redefining `total_ID_list` inside the loop.. did you want to use `total_ID_list[[m]]` instead of `total_ID_list[[l]]`? As @coatless suggested, you should preallocate your vector (or better an array) of the size corresponding to your sequences of `i`, `j`, `k` and `l`.

Comment: Thank you everybody for taking the time to answer. I really apologize for the bad code that didn't work. It was late, and I actually thought it would work. I have now updated my code so it should run and work as intended. The end output `log_like_list` is (in this case) a list of 120 values (at least if you use `unlist` on it). And that is how it is supposed to be. As stated, my problem is that the loops in this case is a few, and `n = 4`. In reality `n = 1000` and the loops are roughly `seq(1, 150, 0.1)` for the first, `seq(0.1, 2, 0.01)` for the second, and `seq(0.1, 1, 0.01)` for the third.

Comment: So instead of a end list of 120 values it should be a list of 30.000.000 values. And as you can imagine, this last list consists of 30 mio. single values, which has been calculated from values of `n = 1000`. So basically, I end up having to do roughly 30 billion calculations. And I understand that that takes some time - but with this, it will take forever. So that was my main goal for this question: Can I optimize it in any way so it maybe just take a fraction of this.

Comment: Oops, instead of 120 values, it is of course 10.000 with the current code found in the OP now. 10.000 values in the last list, not 120. And again, as stated, with the number of values I am going through I can calculate about 1000 per second with the current code. So that will take me forever if I am to calculate about 30 billion.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your approach. If you really need to calculate and store that many numbers then you need to focus on vectorizing as much as possible. There is no reason to be looping though fixed vectors like `i` and `j`, define them and do some of the simple steps like multiplying them outside.   Also make sure you are o R 3.5 since it has specific improvements for large vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current edit is still wrong,
you probably shouldn't be re-defining `log_like_list` inside any of the loops.
Here's an alternative that first allocates all parameter combinations with `expand.grid`,
which is a bit wasteful in terms of RAM,
but I think it's manageable:

```
n <- 4L
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1L:n,
  yesNo = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n),
  ID_specific_data = floor(runif(n, min=10, max=100))
)

params <- expand.grid(
  i = seq(1, 100, 1),
  j = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1),
  k = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)
)

log_like <- sapply(1L:nrow(params), function(row_id) {
  i <- params$i[row_id]
  j <- params$j[row_id]
  k <- params$k[row_id]

  calc <- sapply(df$ID_specific_data, function(idsd) {
    x <- (idsd * k - j) / (i * j)
    pnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
  })

  sum(df$yesNo * log(calc) + (1 - df$yesNo) * log(1 - calc))
})
```

However, for your final use case, this is probably still too slow...
You can try to use parallelization,
which might have acceptable times if you have many cores:

```
library(doParallel)
library(itertools)

# do NOT run these lines several times without calling stopCluster() on the created workers
workers <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(workers)

n <- 1000L
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1L:n,
  yesNo = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n),
  ID_specific_data = floor(runif(n, min=10, max=100))
)

params <- expand.grid(
  i = seq(1, 150, 0.1),
  j = seq(0.1, 2, 0.01),
  k = seq(0.1, 1, 0.01)
)

params_chunk <- isplitRows(params, chunks = getDoParWorkers())
log_like_par <- foreach(param = params_chunk, .combine = c, .multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {
  # return from foreach body here
  sapply(1L:nrow(param), function(row_id) {
    i <- param$i[row_id]
    j <- param$j[row_id]
    k <- param$k[row_id]

    calc <- sapply(df$ID_specific_data, function(idsd) {
      x <- (idsd * k - j) / (i * j)
      pnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
    })

    # return from sapply body here
    sum(df$yesNo * log(calc) + (1 - df$yesNo) * log(1 - calc))
  })
}

stopCluster(workers); registerDoSEQ()
```

I tried running it in my system (4 cores),
but stopped it after a few minutes.
If you wait it out, let me know how long it took.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be a 100% answer that you can copy and paste, but I think it will help you get part of the way.  Mainly you need to think about why it is that you are spending time doing loops where you are really dealing with essentially constant values.

For example

```
i <- seq(1, 100, 1)
j <- seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)
ioxj <- i %o% j
df_ij <- data.frame("i" = i, "j" = j, "ioxj" = ioxj)
df_ij$ixj <- df_ij$i * df_ij$j
```

Will get you every combination of i and j and their product and there is no reason to use a loop to get that basic math result. You might use a loop to go through the columns at some point, that would potentially make sense because the values of i and j might change.
You can also work similarly with k.

Also there is never a reason to do something like this
`x = (df$ID_specific_data[[l]]*k - j) / (i*j)`
in a loop going over each row in a data frame, that loses the whole idea of vectorization, you want to end up with this instead.
`x = (df$ID_specific_data*k - j) / (i*j)`

You need to play around with the code to get it exactly the way you want it, but it will be worth spending the time to do so.  It's possible the occasional loop may be correct but I think you will likely end up doing something much simpler.